# UIView animatewithduration skips animation on iOS 7 but works fine on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I'm working an app that has a spinning wheel with four tiles as a menu. Should the user pick a tile on the wheel that is not facing down the wheel will auto-rotate to make that tile face down. Then it proceeds to select itself and so on. It's what the customer asked for. The problem is that when tile 1 (with a rotation value of M_PI) is selected it skips the slow steady animation, that otherwise works perfectly on iOS 8 and for the other tiles with different rotation values, and instead jumps.

To sum up: With animationDuration set to M_PI it behaves weirdly on iOS7. Not 8.

Here is some code:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     wheel.container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                   //completion code                         
                 }
 ];
```

Comment: Please refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922752/rotate-uiimageview-around-its-center-point/19922979#19922979

Comment: I looked at it. Couldn't really translate it into anything that I could use. :-(

Answer (score 0):

It could also be related to the the data type, like M_PI is double or float. Also how does rotation is being calculated and what it's data type is -

I was also facing similar issue once and I limited the number of digits after decimal in M_PI to around 6 (like #define M_PI_S   3.141592), which worked for me.

At least you try this once it could work.

I wrote the code as

```
#define M_PI_S   3.141592   /* pi */
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle / 180.0 * M_PI_S)

- (void)rotateImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration curve:(int)curve degrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    CGAffineTransform transform =
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
    image.transform = transform;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and called the function as -

```
[self rotateImage:variationCell.m_helpImage duration:0.25
                            curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn degrees:90];
```

Comment: I had to modify your suggestion a bit, since I'm rotating a UIView and not an imageview. Also the particular object doesn't have a m_helpImage. I was able to build and run it, but sadly it didn't fix it. Rotation actually stopped completely. I replaced what I posted with a call to your function with the appropriate values, but for some reason it didn't work at all. Maybe I should try again.

Comment: thanks for modifying & trying, I just posted the sample code (I was using this in my project)